# Show close button on PayTM gateway with Android

Tags: android, paytm

I have integrated Paytm API on my Android App. Payment part works correctly but I can't cancel the transaction (just in case if I want to add some more items so there would be an update in the amount to paid), there is no cancel button or close. How do I implement this?

[image]

I was checking Uber App they have Action bar shown in the top. Is it possible to implement Paytm gateway to open on a web view or dialog box or something? If so how?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a blind guess. Add an entry in AndroidManifest for PayTm activity that just opened with the theme and all. It will override the theme (which probably will be the full screen in your case).

Comment: @Killer I don't have control with paytm activity that is the issue.